# how to divide the request using ingress?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, nginx-ingress

I have application "test.abc.com". I want to transfer request between different service.

**Example or Expected output**

- when user hit `test.abc.com` --> it will go to  `abc-demo-frontend-external` service
- when user hit `test.abc.com/main.js` --> it will go to  `abc-demo-frontend` service

I added below code but it is not working

**current output**
when user hit `test.abc.com` or `test.abc.com/main.js` both request going to `abc-demo-frontend` ? why ?

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: test-demo-frontend-ingress
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    spec:
      rules:
        - host: "test.abc.com"
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /*
                pathType: ImplementationSpecific
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: abc-demo-frontend
                    port:
                      number: 80
              - path: /
                pathType: ImplementationSpecific
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: abc-demo-frontend-external
                    port:
                      number: 80
```

any idea..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: test-demo-frontend-ingress
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'false'
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    spec:
      rules:
        - host: "test.abc.com"
          http:
            paths:
              - path: /(.+\.(css|js))
                pathType: ImplementationSpecific
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: abc-demo-frontend
                    port:
                      number: 80
              - path: /
                pathType: ImplementationSpecific
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: abc-demo-frontend-external
                    port:
                      number: 80
```

Comment: thanks for answering .but it is not correct there are so many request like `test.abc.com/main.js`,`test.abc.com/abc.js`,`test.abc.com/jjds.css` ". all request goes to `abc-demo-frontend` .. Only `/` will go `abc-demo-frontend-external`

Comment: any idea or suggestion ?

Comment: can you please delete this answer

Comment: can you please update your question first with proper details of CSS and JS you mentioned just main.js.

Comment: and sorry can't delete my answer, i have updated it please feel free to give it try once.